# Container alingments in jframe

Tags: java, jframe

I want to align components in flowlayout.is it possible?
Here is my code:

```
JPanel ppanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    ppanel.add(text);
    ppanel.add(btnLogin);
    ppanel.add(btnRegister);

    text.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    btnLogin.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    btnRegister.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
```

[image: picture]

i want to move Label "Welcome" to far left and 2 buttons for far right
Any suggestions?

Comment: No, it is not possible with FlowLayout.  Use a [horizontal Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createHorizontalBox--) with [glue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createHorizontalGlue--) or use a GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         yourpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         yorpanelpanel.add(yourbutton,BorderLayout.WEST);
         yorpanelpanel.add(yourbutton,BorderLayout.EAST);
```

you might wanna try this code,